# Ссылки для слов в строке js

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня есть строка в которой слова идут через запятую, например "работа, стартап, информационные технологии". Необходимо с помощью js или jquery каждое слово или словосочетание до запятой сделать ссылкой. Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "работа, стартап, информационные технологии",
arr = str.split(', '),
links = arr.map(function (text) {return /*возвращайте тут свою ссылку.*/});
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!